# Connection string not found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I have `WPF` app. It has 3 layers, Data, Business and Presentation. I fetch data using `Data` layer and have connection string in it.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="StockDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/StockContext.csdl|res://*/StockContext.ssdl|res://*/StockContext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\StockDB.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

but still it is throwing run time error.

> No connection string named 'StockDBEntities' could be found in the application config file.

So what could be the problem. I have `mdf` file in `App_Data` folder (folder I created manually).

**PS**

I have moved mdf file from project root to App_Data folder after connection string was created.

Comment: Do you only have a single project? How exactly are you fetching the connection string?

Comment: @vesan I am using Entity framework.

Comment: Do you only have a single project?

Comment: @vesan No, separate proj for each layer

Comment: Then make sure that the connection string is in the `app.config` file for the project that will be your `exe`. You might also need to copy some of the other config sections that entity framework generates.

Comment: Put your connection string on your startup project in this case your wpf layer

Comment: do you use connection string in your constractor Or leave it blank ? for example Public StockDBEntities():base("StockDBEntities")   -> Or public StockDBEntities() ?

Answer (score 0):

The connection string should be available in the config file of your WPF project.

.Net searches for the configuration value in the config file of the executing assembly, which is in your case, WPF application. So make sure the connection string is there in app.config file.